# Kali Linux Persistence won't work

Tags: kali-linux, live-usb, settings, persistence

I am running kali on USB Persistence.

I am storing many files in it, but I have problems with settings.

My settings changes are not saved.

I am trying to make a new account but not working.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to U&L , Are you followed the official docs : [Kali Linux Live USB Persistence](https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence)

Comment: Yes, I have followed it.

Comment: "_I have problems with settings_" and "_but not working_". Unless you explain what problems you're having, and what the symptoms are of it "not working" it's almost impossible to give you suggestion on what to try. Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/385851/edit) to provide more detail. (What did you try? What happened? What did you expect to happen? What didn't happen that you did expect? Precisely what error messages did you get? What have you done to try and resolve the issue yourself?)

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 types of installation on a USB stick
1) "Normal". This is like a LiveCD and any changes will be lost
2) "Persistent". This is where you can change some stuff, like in Home, but you cannot save everything, such as configurations
3) "Full". This is a full and proper install. Everything is saved.

The size of the stick is a restriction

See e.g. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/running-linux-usb-right/

Comment: Link changed...